# Округление при делении элементов массива

Tags: java

Есть задача: Поделить некие числа, округлить результат (к примеру 3.5 = 4, а 3.4 = 3).
Так как чисел крайне много (А при неправильном ответе они генерятся заного),
было принято распихать их в массивы и поделить.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Float[] array1 = new Float[]{17731f, 8258729f, 1842420f, -7477958f, -5325198f, 7533f, 9311857f, 1227251f, 3774300f, -6514445f, 18841f, -6869139f};
    Float[] array2 = new Float[]{1650f, 870f, 443f, -4961846f, -1654021f, 432f, 883f, 13f, -3926118f, 3875184f, 1594f, 521510f};
    float gg = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        gg = array1[i] / array2[i];
        Math.round(gg);
        System.out.printf("%s ",gg);
    }
}
```

`Math.round` Не дает к слову вообще никакого результата. Прога делит правильно, но нужного результата (округления) она не дает.

Если кто осведомлен в Java, прошу помощи.
Задачка с сайта "codeabbey.com" -Rounding #6.
Заранее извиняюсь за криворукость, только учусь еще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что вы должны обратно вернуть округленное значение. То есть [округление](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) не присваивается обратно в `gg`.

Вместо строчки `Math.round(gg);` надо написать `gg = Math.round(gg);`

Если вы хотите выводить строго целочисленный тип - сделайте приведение к типу `int`:

```
int gi = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    gg = array1[i] / array2[i];
    gi = (int) Math.round(gg);
    System.out.printf("%s ",gi);
}
```

---

[Пример на ideone](https://ideone.com/OEj5S4).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да это сработало. Но к сожалению я ошибся. "Math" мне не помог с решением. А как я могу их округлить следуя условию к примеру 11/2=5.5 =6 или 156/66=2.36... = 2. А так же убрать "#.0" из ответа. Сайт очень критичный и ответы в формате "11.0" не принимает, только "11".

Comment: @Bogdan обновил ответ, посмотрите. `Math.Round` как раз-таки нужен в этом случае, если вам нужно округление. Проверьте сами - он так и работает.

Comment: Забыл поблагодарить) Спасибо, все отлично подошло)